# How to calculate average annual salary in libreoffice calc

Tags: formula, average, spreadsheet, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have salary data table from 10 years period. Every column has properly set data type (date for "B", number for "C" and "E".

[image: sample data table]

I'm trying to write a formula to calculate average salary for every year. In column "E" I've manually entered all possible years and in column "F" should be an yearly average, according to year from "E".

So, my best try is this formula: `=AVERAGEIF(YEAR(B2:B133);"="&E2;C2:C133)`

Trying so calculate an average from column C, where year in date from column B equals a year in column E

[image: averageif formula]

But all I get is an error Err:504. Figured out, that problem is in `YEAR(interval)` part, but can't get what exactly...

Can someone point that out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually many possibilities to solve this.

- @JvdV [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62339785/4540413);
- using an array formula with @JvdV solution;
- using an array formula with a combination of `AVERAGE()` and `IF()`;
- using the `SUMPRODUCT()` function;
- and surely many other solutions that I don't know about!

**Please beware:** I use `,` instead of `;` as formula separator, according to my locale; adapt to your needs.

#### A side note on "array formulas"

This kind of formulas are applied by mandatory pressing the `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` key combination to insert them, not only `Enter` or `Tab` or mouse-clicking elsewhere on the sheet.
The resulting formula is shown between brackets `{}`, which are not inserted by the user but are automatically shown by the software to inform that this is actually an array formula.
More on array formulas i.e. [on the LibreOffice help system](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html).

Usually you cannot drag and drop array formulas, you have to copy-paste them instead.

#### Array formula with @JvdV solution

The solution of JvdV could be slighly modified like this, and then inserted as an array formula:

> =AVERAGEIFS(C$2:C$133,YEAR($B$2:$B$133),"="&E2)

When you insert this formula with the Ctrl + Shift + Enter key combination, the software puts the formula into brackets, so that you see it like this: `{=AVERAGEIFS(C$2:C$133,YEAR($B$2:$B$133),"="&E2)}`

You cannot simply drag the formula down, but you can copy-paste it.

#### Array formula with a combination of `AVERAGE()` and `IF()`:

For your example, put this formula in cell `F2` (for the year 2010):

> =AVERAGE(IF(YEAR($B$2:$B$133)=E2,$C$2:$C$133))

When you insert this formula with the `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` key combination, the software puts the formula into brackets, so that you see it like this `{=AVERAGE(IF(YEAR($B$2:$B$133)=E2,$C$2:$C$133))}`

You cannot simply drag the formula down, but you can copy-paste it.

#### SUMPRODUCT() formula:

My loved one...
Plenty of resources on the web to explain this formula.
In your situation, this would give:

> =SUMPRODUCT($C$2:$C$133,--(YEAR($B$2:$B$133)=E2))/SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR($B$2:$B$133)=E2))

This one you can drag down to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `AVERAGEIF()` expects a range reference instead of a calculated array. Therefor it will error out. That's the theory at least for Excel, and I expect this to be the same for LibreCalc.

One way around it is using the `AVERAGEIFS()` function and check against first and last days of the year, for example:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(C$2:C$133;B$2:B$133;">="&DATE(E2;1;1);B$2:B$133;"<="&DATE(E2;12;31))
```

Drag the formula down.